# Alignment of <div>'s with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make boxes to list upcoming events and am having trouble getting them aligned horizontally. I am using Codepen.io, I will link what I have done. I thought makings a second box #two with the exact details as the first box #one and just moving to the right would work, but I do not know why it doesn't. I made sure not to nest it within the first box #one and just inside the .container .

https://codepen.io/bibaboy/pen/YzVJWKR

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#3f5efb, #fc466b);
}

.container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px double black;
}

#one {
  width: 20%;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 #e667b8;
}

#two {
  width: 20%;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 #e667b8;
}

#header1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #477ced;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

#p1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="one">
    <p id="header1">September 15 2021</p>
    <hr>
    <p id="p1"> We will be holding a conference for blahblah company in the <b>7th floor of the IBC Bank building</b>.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="two">
    <p id="header1"> Hello Hello </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox for something like this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

I think this solves the problem your having. I gave the divs with id "**one**" and "**two**" a generic class of "**box**", and removed the margin. Then I added the following flex styles to the container class:

```
display: flex;

align-items: center;

justify-content: space-around;
```

display: flex; makes the container into flex container, align-items: center; centers the items vertically, and justify-content: space-evenly; puts the same amount of space on both sides of each item.

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">
    <p id="header1">September 15 2021</p>
    <hr>
    <p id="p1"> We will be holding a conference for blahblah company in the <b>7th floor of the IBC Bank building</b>.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p id="header1"> Hello Hello </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#3f5efb, #fc466b);
}

.container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px double black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
  width: 20%;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 #e667b8;
}

#header1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #477ced;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

#p1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! Now that they are centered at least, I can continue to mess around with the code to position more on certain areas of the display. Thank you very much!